# Allow to override/set constraints validation for a child object for Hibernate validation

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have the following class :

```java
class ContactInformation {
   String phone;
   String email;
}
```

which is used in the following classes :

```java
class Person {
   @Valid
   ContactInformation contactInformation;
}
```

```java
class Station {
   @Valid
   ContactInformation contactInformation;
}
```

The thing is that any instance of Person must have an email, but it is an optional information for Station. Do I have a way to define this at owner level to avoid duplicate the class `ContactInformation` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `field` level validator you can add the `Type` level validator.
Steps:

- Define Type level annotation
- Write Validator for new annotation
- Introduce your type with a new annotation

Define:

```java
    @Constraint(validatedBy = {PersonClassOptionalEmailValidator.class})
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface PersonalEmailValid {
        String message() default "Invalid Email address";

        Class<?>[] groups() default {};

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    }
```

Writing Custom Validator:

```java
    public static class PersonClassOptionalEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PersonalEmailValid, Person> {
        // Test Email validator, you should check prope regex for production
        public static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$";
        private final Pattern pattern;


        public PersonClassOptionalEmailValidator() {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_REGEX);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Person person, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            if (person.contactInformation != null) {
                return pattern.matcher(person.contactInformation.email).matches();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Introduce new annotation to class

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @PersonalEmailValid
    static class Person {
        @Valid
        ContactInformation contactInformation;
    }
```

[Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints)

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/silentsudo/a7e86d76bb4f21812febc8d1ac044002)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would really like to avoid creating a custom validator for that.